# Entity Framework not mapping 1 to 1 Relationship

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I have some tables and I can't get them to map.

```
aspnet_Users
UserId<PK>
//Other Fields

Table A(intermediate table)
UserId<PK>


Table B
UserId<PK>
Field1
Field2
Field3
```

Yep when I add these 3 tables in I will either get a 1 to 1 relationship with

aspnet_users to Table A

or

Table A to Table B

I need to have

aspnetusers to Table A to Table B

I tried to add this association but it never works.

```
Error 3021: Problem in Mapping Fragment starting at line 168: Each of the following columns in TableA is mapped to multiple conceptual side properties:
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the intermediate table is just a relationship mapping table (has a aspUser.userid and tableb.userid column) Entity framework cuts it out and only displays aspnet_Users to TableB.

If it is as you say above then you should see a chain of all three tables.

In your database do you have foreign key relationships from aspnet_Users to tableA  and Tablea to tableB?

1st relationship: aspnet_Users.UserID=TableA.UseID
2nd relationship: TableA.UserID=TableB.UseID

If you do this then refresh you Entity Data Model from the database and it should show three tables asp_users to tableA and tableA to tableB mapping.  Note that you may have to close/reopen the edmx file to see the correct joins and the designer sometimes doesn't refresh.[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe I am not adding the associations the right way. How did you do it? I can't get my tables to show up like yours.

Comment: Added the DB Relationships screen shots for TableA

Comment: I don't have that Foreign Key Relationships window. Where is it? I can't find it.

Comment: oh wait that is for sql. I see that

Comment: Ok It works. I did not know the thing was so picky. I just dragged the relationship in SQl from one primary key to another since I thought it did not matter which way it went in this case since they both are primary keys.

Comment: Now I need to figure out how to get Roles and UserInRoles to work together

Comment: Sorry I stepped away for a few hours :)  Did you get everything working?  Users and roles will be a bit different probably and you will have a Users, a Roles and a mapping table with 2 columns, UserID and RoleID.  When you set up your foreign keys in SQL you will only see two mapped tables in Entity designer, it hides the mapping table on purpose.  GL and hit me up if you have any more questions.